# Changing an inline img element to act like a block element

Tags: html, css, inline

I'm new to this world, but loving it so. Please excuse my newbie status if I ask ridiculous questions or if things are not posting quite right. Please advise as you see fit.

I am trying to get a button to float over an image. I've brought the image in as an in-line element so that I can preserve the PSD link in Dreamweaver, rather than bringing it in as a background image and for the alt attribute applications. I'm guessing the problem is that I want the inline image to act as a block? Is that right? I've been able to get the button to float over the image using relative positioning for the button and absolute positioning for the image, but then am unable to center the whole thing on the page. Any advice you have is greatly appreciated!

**CSS**

```
#container {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
}

#button {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<body>

  <div id="container"><img src="index.jpg" width="1200" height="900" /></div> 

  <div id="button"></div>

</body>
```

Comment: You want the blue background over the image - all of which is centered on the screen?

Answer (score 0):

Move your button div inside your content div:

```
<div id="container"><img src="index.jpg" width="1000" height="900" /><div id="button"></div></div>
```

And then change your container to be the width of your content. Position set to relative. Then, position the button inside the container div with absolute, top, and left.

```
#container {
margin: auto;
display: block;
width:1200px;
position:relative;
}

#button {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background-color: blue;
position: absolute;
top:0px; left:20px;
}
```